# Port a project from sybase to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I want to port a project from sybase to oracle. I need to port the tables scripts (around 30) and some data in meta data tables(100 rows 2/3 tables). What will the best tool for this work?

Answer (score 1):

For such a small volume you would be well of writing the scripts rather than using any tools.

Answer (score 0):

You do have scripts for the tables in sybase, right?  Conversion by manually editing should be doable, as Dheer said.

What meta data are you referring to?  Is it meta data you've generated or meta data that sybase generated as a consequence ofr your DDL scripts?

If it's meta data you've generated, you migrate it like any other data.

If it's system generated meta data, you are better off not to migrate it, but to adapt your usage to Oracle's meta data, stored in system tables usually referred to as the Oracle Data dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that oracle sqldeveloper will do this.

see http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/index_sqldev_omwb.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys...
I did the conversion manually but Matt Ball is right. Oracle SQl developer is a good tool. I figured it out later.I have  Version 1.5.1 installed.

But the trick is to update the extension. By default it come with only Access SQL to Oracle. Here are the steps.

1. Go to Tools>preferences>Web Browser and Proxy set your Proxy
2. Go to Tools>preferences>Extensions click check for Updates
   You should get Sybase driver and translator once you install that (Requires oracle website id and password) restart
3. Go to Migration >Translation scratch editor should have sybase TSql drop down. Copy paste your scripts and enjoy...

Insert scripts you have to add Bla_Sequence.nextval by your own.